# High pressure cryonics

Tags: biology, medical-physics, cryogenics

In this link, it is suggested to use high-pressure cryonics to freeze living cells, tissues or small organism as opposed to various and potentially toxic anti-freeze agent. The core idea is that over a certain pressure, ice is anamorphic and will not form ice crystals. Thus, organic matter will not be destroyed by said crystals.

Detailed information about the proposal can be found at this link:

https://www.benbest.com/cryonics/pressure.html

I have considering self-financing the experiment. Could anyone chip in with some advice? Do you see any red flags, design tips, etc.?

Comment: Exciting project. Although I'm not sure what this question is asking for. Reading that long article in the link and then give advice? I'm afraid I think questions for this site must be more specific. Possibly, the SE Engineering site is more fitting for this type of prototype-creation-experiment question.

Comment: either https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/ or https://biology.stackexchange.com/ should be a better fit. Other than that, extremely interesting stuff! +1

Comment: A key question is whether it denaturates proteins too badly. Proteins do change under high (~100 MPa) pressure, https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsif.2018.0244 https://febs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1432-1033.1994.tb18774.x

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by problems (technical difficulties, biology,...). One big issue here is that in your reference, they are talking about thousands of atmospheres of pressure. Safety will be a very important issue. Just look at what can happen when an airplane tire explodes (less than 100 atmospheres for sure, probably closer to 40-50) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TWAR1KtYJU. The whole video is interesting, but you want to look at what happens between 1:44 and 1:54. You want to pressurize stuff to at least 20 and maybe 200 times that pressure. Any containment failure will be ugly. You can also Google what happened when Mythbusters exploded some water heaters with pressure. Very educative videos. If you don't know how to build things made to withstand such pressures, don't do it yourself. Maybe if you have access to a bunker or a very large field you could operate things remotely, but treat any pressurized chamber that you build yourself as an armed bomb ready to explode any time you pressurize it.

Comment: My questions specifically, is does amorphous ice, such as the type produced by a high pressure system, damages (small/microscopic) biological material.